# Is there a way to skin YouTrack?

Tags: youtrack

We'd like to customize YouTrack colors (and maybe even add the company logo) to our YouTrack standalone installation.

One of the main reasons: it will give us instant feedback that we are using our corporate YouTrack, rather than the public ones (e.g. at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JT).

Is this possible? Is it a licensing restriction?

Comment: BTW, see http://blog.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2012/09/creating-an-alternative-ui-for-youtrack/ if you want to create a completely new UI for YouTrack.  Not exactly "skinning", though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application logo can be customized via

"Settings" -> "Visual" -> "Application logo"

This feature is not available with free licenses though.

Color scheme can't be changed at all, but they seem to have a feature request you can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-12923

Comment: FYI:  I also started using the "System-wide banner" (in the settings) to differentiate between environments.